# Asp.Net update image url

Tags: asp.net, image

I have a image control and button control.I want to choose new image and update image with button click.
cs file like below:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//choose new image 
        }
```

Comment: I want to do it dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this on your .ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" /><br /><br />
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</form>
```

And in your .CS:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/YourImageFolder") + filename);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/YourImageFolder" + filename;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  image1.ImageUrl = "~/FolderName/yourimage.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I want to do it dynamically

Comment: Give some more details what is your requirement.

Comment: I want using dynamically FileUpload

Comment: then u need to save that image in folder then map it to image control.